# Как загрузить библиотеку JQuery при XSLT трансформации в HTML документ?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, xml, xslt

Есть ли способ подгрузить JQuery при XSLT трансформации? У меня есть проект, который преобразует XML в HTML документ, но как бы я не пытался загрузить JQuery у меня это не получалось. Признаться, у меня вообще не получилось подгрузить ни один js файл при преобразовании. В моём проекте есть возможность использовать ActiveX, он написан на С#, можно ли с его помощью подгрузить JQuery?

Comment: Предвижу комментарии по поводу того что ActiveX ни у кого работать не будет. Отвечу сразу, что проект внутрикорпоративный, запускается не из браузера, а посредством другого приложения, который использует библиотеку ie7 и там доступ к ActiveX открыт.

Comment: Я всё таки решил эту проблему. Расскажу для тех кто возможно столкнётся с этой бедой, тем более нигде больше я не нашёл данного решения. Чтоб подключить jquery требуется инициализировать библиотеку динамически, следующим образом:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" defer="true">
<xsl:text>
function func() {
var newscript = document.createElement('script');
newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
newscript.async = true;
newscript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
}

          setTimeout(func, 1000);

          </xsl:text>
      </script>